# Ordnance Survey 100m Grid shapefile

Tags: qgis, grids-graticules, ordnance-survey

I want to add a 100m (hectare) grid layer to my UK map and have been trying to use the FSC's OSGR tool. It is incredibly slow to process, therefore I'm wondering is there are any shapefiles available at this resolution that would do a better job?

Looking back at previous threads I can see that other OS grid shapefiles are available via a couple of Github areas, however there is not one for 100m as far as I can see.

Maybe there is a way I can generate my own? I'm relatively new to GIS (using QGIS at the moment).

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Try Create Grid tool. But it is going to be a huge grid with 100 m sides... Why do you need it, just for visual purpose?

Comment: Thanks @BERA . I will be using it to quantify landcover types. Ideally identifying wholly urban squares.

Comment: Your landcover data is in vector format? I think working with rasters would be better. Creating a 100*100 m raster is much faster than 100*100 m vector grid.